# Moq mock generic and expression function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, mocking, moq

I'm getting some issues while I try to mock a delegate. What I have so far is:

Interface ISpecification:

```
TResult FindOne<T, TResult>(
    ISpecification<T> criteria, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> property)
    where T : class;
```

Implementation Specification:

```
public virtual TResult FindOne<T, TResult>(
    ISpecification<T> criteria, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> property)
    where T : class
{
      return criteria.SatisfyingItemFrom(GetQuery<T>(), property);
}
```

Call that I'm trying to mock:

```
var spec = new MySpecification(Id, s).OrderByDescending(x => x.Code).Take(1);
string LineId = _Repository.FindOne(spec, line => line.Id);
```

The mock that I have so far (that is not working):

```
_warehouseRepositoryMock
.Setup(x => x.FindOne(It.IsAny<MySpecification>(),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Line, object>>>()))
.Returns(TestLine.Id);
```

The error that I'm getting is:

Moq.MockException : IGenericRepository.FindOne(Specification`1[Line], line => line.Id) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

But I'm unsure how to send line => line.Id into my mock.

Comment: What type is `line.Id`?

Comment: It's a string but when I change from object to string it gives the same error.

Comment: Did you try to use `ISpecification<Line>`instead of `MySpecification`: `_warehouseRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.FindOne(It.IsAny<ISpecification<Line>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Line, string>>>()))
    .Returns(TestLine.Id);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the `It.IsAny<T>()` clauses have to match the declaration.

Using

```
TResult FindOne<T, TResult>(
    ISpecification<T> criteria,
    Expression<Func<T, TResult>> property) where T : class;
```

with `T as Line` and `TResult as string` it gives you the equivalent of

```
string FindOne(
    ISpecification<Line> criteria,
    Expression<Func<Line, string>> property);
```

and the setup therefore has to be

```
_warehouseRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.FindOne(
    It.IsAny<ISpecification<Line>>(),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Line, string>>>())).Returns(TestLine.Id);
```

If you want to restrict `criteria`to any type or subtype of `MySpecification` you can setup with `It.Is<T>()`:

```
_warehouseRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.FindOne(
    It.Is<ISpecification<Line>>(s => s is MySpecification),
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Line, string>>>())).Returns(TestLine.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you abto - I was thinking it was the function call that was failing - didn't think it was because of ISpec. Thank you very much